# MYSQL- Displaying data while looping through week ending dates

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

For the past month of so, I have been creating a benchmark system that allows for users to add categories & benchmarkitems that retain data by every week within a specific year. I having trouble creating a mysql statement that shows each benchmarkitem with its results for all weeks within the yr even if for that week there is no data or no data for the year. Below are the queries I have been testing with and the table columns. I am using codeigniter and plan to display the results in format mapped out at the bottom. I apologize for this lengthy description but I am attempting to be as clear as possible. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
tblbenchmarkitem
=================
itemID | itemDescription | itemTarget | ItemFreq | FKcategoryID

tblbenchmarkData
================
dataID | FKitemID | resultDate | result | dateAdded | dateModified

tblcategories
===============
categoryID | categoryName | parentID | FKdeptID

tblcalendardates  - stores 52 weeks for year Saturday to Friday
================
id | year | startDate | endDate
```

These are my mysql statements in the model. I am going to set a default value in the function param for the year.

```
public function get_data() {
    $dates = $this->db->query("SELECT endDate FROM tblcalendardates WHERE year = '2014' ORDER BY endDate");
    $dates = $dates->result();
    foreach ($dates as $date ) {
        //$query = "SELECT tblcalendardates.enddate, tblbenchmarkitems.itemDescription, tblbenchmarkitems.itemTarget, tblbenchmarkitems.itemFrequency, tblbenchmarkdata.resultDate, IFNULL(tblbenchmarkdata.result,0) AS result, (SELECT strCategoryName FROM tblcategories WHERE tblbenchmarkitems.FKcategoryID = tblcategories.categoryID) AS category FROM tblbenchmarkdata LEFT JOIN tblbenchmarkitems ON tblbenchmarkdata.FKitemID = tblbenchmarkitems.itemID JOIN tblcalendardates WHERE DATE(tblbenchmarkdata.resultDate) BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(tblcalendardates.startdate)) FROM tblcalendardates WHERE tblcalendardates.year = " . date('Y') . ") AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(tblcalendardates.enddate)) FROM tblcalendardates WHERE tblcalendardates.year = " . date('Y') . ") GROUP BY category ORDER BY tblcalendardates.enddate";
        $query = 'SELECT c.*, i.itemDescription, i.itemTarget, IFNULL(d.result, 0) as result,"' . $date ->endDate . '" FROM tblcategories AS c JOIN tblbenchmarkitems AS i ON i.FKcategoryID = c.categoryID JOIN tblbenchmarkdata as d ON i.itemID = d.FKitemID JOIN tblcalendardates WHERE DATE(d.resultDate) BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(tblcalendardates.startdate)) FROM tblcalendardates WHERE tblcalendardates.year = "' . date('Y') . '") AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(tblcalendardates.enddate)) FROM tblcalendardates WHERE tblcalendardates.year = "' . date('Y') . '") GROUP BY strCategoryName';
        $query = $this->db->query($query);

    return $query->result();
    }
}
```

this is in my view

```
<table class="table table-hover data-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="th-set-width1">Benchmark Item</th>
          <th class="th-set-width2">Target</th>
        <?php foreach( $weeks as $week ): ?>
          <th class="th-set-width2"><?php echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime($week->enddate)); ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach( $entries as $entry ) : ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry->itemDescription; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $entry->itemTarget; ?></td>
          <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 52; $i++) : ?>
            <?php if ($entry->result != NULL || $entry->result > 0): ?>
              <td><?php echo $entry->result; ?></td>
            <?php else: ?>
              <td>0</td>
            <?php endif; ?>
          <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how I want to display the data in a table.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
categoryName
====================================================================================
itemDescription |  itemTarget | 01-03-14 | 01-10-14 | 01-17-14 | 01-24-14 | 01-31-14
=====================================================================================
No. of Visits   |    12.00    |   NULL   |   NULL   |   15.00  |    NULL  |   20.00 
No. of Calls    |    17.00    |   12.00  |   NULL   |   17.00  |    22.00 |   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some changes to my code that almost yields the response I am looking for. The only issue now is that I have two items being displayed with one result for each item.

My Model:

```
public function get_data() {
    $items = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tblbenchmarkitems');
    $items = $items->result();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $query = 'SELECT c.endDate, IFNULL(d.result,0) as result FROM tblbenchmarkdata AS d RIGHT JOIN tblcalendardates as c ON (DATE(d.resultDate) = c.endDate) JOIN tblbenchmarkitems as i  WHERE c.year = "2014" AND i.itemID = "' . $item->itemID .'" GROUP BY c.endDate';
        $query = $this->db->query($query);
        $data[] = array(
            'itemID'            => $item->itemID,
            'itemDescription'   => $item->itemDescription,
            'itemTarget'        => $item->itemTarget,
            'dates'             => $query->result()
        );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

My view:

```
<table class="table table-hover data-list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th-set-width1">Benchmark Item</th>
      <th class="th-set-width2">Target</th>
    <?php foreach( $weeks as $week ): ?>
       <th class="th-set-width2"><?php echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime($week->enddate)); ?></th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  <?php for( $n = 0; $n < count($entries); $n++ ) : ?>

    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entries[$n]['itemDescription']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $entries[$n]['itemTarget']; ?></td>
      <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count($entries[$n]['dates']);  $i++) :?>
      <td><?php echo $entries[$n]['dates'][$i]->result; ?></td>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>

  <?php endfor; ?>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Table Format from Query Result - *Issue is that record one and record two have both results being displayed. Record one has a result recorded on 11/7/14 and record two has a result recorded on 7/11/14*:

```
+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Benchmark Item                           | Target |01-03-2014|01-10-2014|01-17-2014|01-24-2014|01-31-2014|02-07-2014|02-14-2014|02-21-2014|02-28-2014|03-07-2014|03-14-2014|03-21-2014|03-28-2014|04-04-2014|04-11-2014|04-18-2014|04-25-2014|05-02-2014|05-09-2014|05-16-2014|05-23-2014|05-30-2014|06-06-2014|06-13-2014|06-20-2014|06-27-2014|07-04-2014|07-11-2014|07-18-2014|07-25-2014|08-01-2014|08-08-2014|08-15-2014|08-22-2014|08-29-2014|09-05-2014|09-12-2014|09-19-2014|09-26-2014|10-03-2014|10-10-2014|10-17-2014|10-24-2014|10-31-2014|11-07-2014|11-14-2014|11-21-2014|11-28-2014|12-05-2014|12-12-2014|12-19-2014|12-26-2014|
+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Total No. of Calls Conducted               17.00     0.00        0.00        0.00      0.00        0.00       0.00     0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00      0.00      0.00       0.00     0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00      0.00     0.00    0.00     0.00        0.00        0.00        **2.00**        0.00        0.00      0.00     0.00    0.00     0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00      0.00        0.00     0.00         0.00       0.00   **12.00**     0.00        0.00        0.00     0.00      0.00      0.00       0.00   |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Total No. of Random Visits                 29.00     0.00        0.00        0.00      0.00        0.00       0.00     0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00      0.00      0.00       0.00     0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00      0.00     0.00    0.00     0.00        0.00        0.00        **2.00**        0.00        0.00      0.00     0.00    0.00     0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00      0.00        0.00     0.00         0.00       0.00   **12.00**     0.00        0.00        0.00     0.00      0.00      0.00       0.00   |
+-----------------------------------------+--------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

In the model, I changed the query I removed the join to the **tblbenchmarkitems** table and removed the need to specify the **itemID** in the where statement. I added the **FKitemID** field to the output to help with ensuring the result corresponds to specific item being evaluated (i.e, if the items ID is 1 and the results being provided in the array belongs to item with ID 1, then display the data only for the ID 1.)

The function within the **model** that gets the benchmark data.

```
public function get_data() {
    $items = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tblbenchmarkitems');
    $items = $items->result();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $query = 'SELECT c.endDate as weekending, IFNULL(d.result,0) as result, d.FKitemID FROM tblbenchmarkdata AS d RIGHT JOIN tblcalendardates as c ON (DATE(d.resultDate) = c.endDate) WHERE c.year = "2014" GROUP BY weekending';
        $query = $this->db->query($query);
        $data[] = array(
            'itemID'            => $item->itemID,
            'itemDescription'   => $item->itemDescription,
            'itemTarget'        => $item->itemTarget,
            'dates'             => $query->result()
        );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

The **view**:

```
<table class="table table-hover data-list">
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="th-set-width1">Benchmark Item</th>
       <th class="th-set-width2">Target</th>

    <?php foreach( $weeks as $week ): ?>
        <th class="th-set-width2"><?php echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime($week->enddate)); ?></th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

     </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  <?php for( $n = 0; $n < count($entries); $n++ ) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $entries[$n]['itemDescription']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $entries[$n]['itemTarget']; ?></td>

     <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count($entries[$n]['dates']);  $i++) :?>
       <?php if ( $entries[$n]['itemID'] == $entries[$n]['dates'][$i]->FKitemID ) : ?>

       <td><?php echo $entries[$n]['dates'][$i]->result; ?></td>

       <?php else: ?>

       <td>0.00</td>

       <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endfor; ?>

   </tr>
  <?php endfor; ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Finally, in the view I added an if statement after the second **for loop** (the one that outputs the data  throughout the weeks). It checks to see if there is a result with the ID of the item being output and if it does then display it only in the row & column it corresponds to. If not then display "0.00".